# Symbol is not in line with text

Tags: html, css, text, symbols

I want to animate this arrow but for some reason it is not in line with the text. could you help me please? :)

https://jsfiddle.net/e3ec86rg/

```
<div id="blogtitle">
<center>
<div id="arrow">&#11015;</div>
<div style="font-size:18px">Now go <span style="color:{color:permalink border}">that way</span></div>
</center>
```

edit: [This is what bothers me](https://jsfiddle.net/e3ec86rg/1/) the arrow is a little bit lower than the text.

Comment: The animation starts above the text, and finishes below -- could you be more precise about how you want it to line up?

Comment: @ovokuro
If you stop the animation the arrow is not in line: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3ec86rg/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to `float` property. Add a negative `margin` to offset it...

```
#arrow {
 font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite ease-in-out;
  margin-top: -2px; /* edit as you need */
  float: left;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/51pm0mvv/1/)

```css
#arrow {
  font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite ease-in-out;
  margin-top: -2px;
  float: left;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0%,
  20%,
  60%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
}

#blogtitle {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: {
    color: blog title
  }
  ;
  font-size:150px;
  letter-spacing:2px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:left;
  width:250px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="blogtitle">
  <center>
    <div id="arrow">&#11015;</div>
    <div style="font-size:18px">Now go <span style="color:{color:permalink border}">that way</span></div>
  </center>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your transform values:

```
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
0%, 20%, 60%, 100%  { -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px); }
40%  { -webkit-transform: translateY(-25px); }
80% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px); }
}
```

```css
#arrow {
    color:{color:permalink border};
    font-size:18px;
    float:left;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite ease-in-out;
   
}


@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
 0%, 20%, 60%, 100%  { -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px); }
    40%  { -webkit-transform: translateY(-25px); }
 80% { -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px); }
}

#blogtitle{
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
    z-index:5;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:{color:blog title};
    font-size:150px;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:left;
    width:250px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="blogtitle">
 <center>
 <div id="arrow">&#11015;</div>
 <div style="font-size:18px">Now go <span style="color:{color:permalink border}">that way</span></div>
 </center>
     
     
 </div>
```

Comment: ugh, that's not what bothers me, sorry. [this is what bothers me](https://jsfiddle.net/e3ec86rg/1/) the arrow is a little bit lower than the text.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3ec86rg/2/)

```
<div id="arrow" style=" margin-top: -3px;">⬇</div>
```